# How to implement a log uniform distribution in Scipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn

I don't understand how to implement the log-uniform probability distribution in Scipy. According to the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977980/4735674), it is possible to do so by defining only `_pdf`. Also, I know from [this source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/190858/72504) the actual derivation for the pdf.

However, I can't figure out where to put the `a` and `b` parameters and how to set `a` such that `a>0`. Also, please note that I want `a` and `b` to be the actual minimum and maximum values of the range. Please also note that, in the end, I really just want to be able to use the `.rvs()` method so any trick with the uniform distribution is acceptable.

Here is my curent (non-working) code:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy as np

class log_uniform_gen(rv_continuous):
    "Log-uniform distribution"
    def _pdf(self, x):
        if np.exp(self.a) <= x <= np.exp(self.b):
            temp = x / (self.b - self.a)
        else:
            temp = 0.

        return temp
log_uniform = log_uniform_gen(a=0.1, b=1.0, name='log-uniform')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my trick to obtain an instance of the log-uniform distribution with the `.rvs()` method:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

class log_uniform():        
    def __init__(self, a=-1, b=0, base=10):
        self.loc = a
        self.scale = b - a
        self.base = base

    def rvs(self, size=None, random_state=None):
        uniform = sp.stats.uniform(loc=self.loc, scale=self.scale)
        if size is None:
            return np.power(self.base, uniform.rvs(random_state=random_state))
        else:
            return np.power(self.base, uniform.rvs(size=size, random_state=random_state))
```

It can be called with `log_uniform(a=2, b=10).rvs(size=10)` where `a` is the exponent of the beginning of the range and `b` is the exponent of the end of range. The base can be modified by using the `base` argument.