# Loguniform distribution using Scipy Stats

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.stats import uniform

def prior_distribution(dist_type, loc, scale):
    if dist_type == 'lognorm':
        dist = lognorm(s=np.log(loc), scale=scale)
    elif dist_type == 'uniform':
        dist = uniform(loc=loc, scale=scale)
    #elif dist_type == 'loguniform':
    return dist
```

I'd like to get the dist for loguniform distribution between 1e-5 and 0.002. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977717/how-do-i-generate-log-uniform-distribution-in-python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate Log Uniform Distribution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977717/how-do-i-generate-log-uniform-distribution-in-python)